# Find the value of $x$ that satisfies the equation $\log_{10} \left(\frac{x^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^{\frac{1}{x+1}}}\right) = 1/5050$ .

Tags: functions, logarithms

I tried it many times and it went bit of lengthy , i reached until

\begin{equation*}
\log_{10}(x^{1/(x^2+x)}) 
\end{equation*}

then i multiplied $2$ both numerator and denominator and then it is consecutive terms in denominator I got my answer $100$. Just want to know if it is correct and a shorter way to solve it ?

Comment: Yeah sorry i mistyped it

Comment: No sweat! Just making sure. So you need to solve $$\frac{1}{x(1+x)}\log_{10}\left(x\right) = \frac{1}{5050}$$ for $x$. I cannot think of a way you can do this algebraically

Comment: Can you edit it ? I am new here and just learning how to use the site

Comment: Is the base $10$ ?

Comment: Yes the base is 10

Comment: @graydad yeah i do not think it can be done algebraically that is the reason i used consecutive terms concept and multiplied 2 both numerator and denominator and then got 100 as answer

Comment: x=100 doesn't statistify

Comment: Try it again .. it is satisfying for me

Comment: @wythagoras Yes it does. In fact, the number $5050$ was always very suspicious, as our first arithmetic progression sum in life is often $1 + 2 + \ldots + 100 = \frac{100 \times 101}{2} = 5050$.

Comment: Yes i got the idea from the same

Comment: Sorry, I somehow thought of log(100) as 10.

Comment: There is also a solution around 1.00091

Comment: @PedroM. you're lucky to remember that! I'm sure that's what the problem writer was thinking, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is equivalent to $$\log(x^{\frac{1}{x(1+x)}})=\frac{1}{5050}$$
Then:

$$x^{\frac{1}{x(1+x)}}=10^{\frac{2}{100*101}}$$
Or 
$$x^{\frac{1}{x(1+x)}}=100^{\frac{1}{100*101}}$$

Thus $x=100$.

Comment: **or $x=10^{.000396582\ldots}$... see @abiessu's solution below for how we know there is more than one solution.

Answer (score 1):

Given

$$\log_{10}\left(\frac{x^\frac 1x}{x^{\frac 1{x+1}}}\right)={1\over 5050}$$

the first couple important transformations are to note $\frac{x^\frac 1x}{x^{\frac 1{x+1}}}=x^{\frac 1{x^2+x}}$, and then that we can rearrange like so:

$$\frac 1{x^2+x}\log_{10} x=\frac 1{5050}\\
\to \log_{10}(x^{5050})=x^2+x\\
\to x^{5050}=10^{x^2+x}$$

Assuming that $x$ is positive, it makes sense to guess that $x=10^k$, yielding

$$10^{5050k}=10^{10^{2k}+10^k}\\
5050k=10^{2k}+10^k\\
10100m=10^{4m}+10^{2m}=10000^m+100^m$$

We can go from "assuming that $x$ is positive" to knowing that it must be (for real $x$), since negative $x$ in $x^{1/{(x^2+x)}}$ is complex ($x^2+x$ is strictly even); therefore, our substitution $x=10^k=100^m$ is legitimate.  Trying the first couple integers $k$ yields a solution $m=1,k=2, x=100$.  A second real-valued solution exists, by noting that $5050k$ changes from greater than $10^{2k}+10^k$ to less than this quantity as $k$ goes from $1$ to $0$.

Comment: exactly the solution I was just going to post! I'll add that I only found $k=2$ by inspection--I know that exponential-equals-linear equations can't be solved in general, so (knowing there's probably an integer solution) I noticed 5050 will look like sums of powers of 10 if we double it. A very pat-yourself-on-the-back-if-you-see-it problem.